# How can I get Content-Length header (Head request method)

Tags: scala, http, spray, akka-http

I don't see any way to get that header in akk-http. That header is removed from header list in HttpResponse.

I know there are methods that return the contentLength from entity:

`HttpEntity.contentLengthOption` 
and 
`HttpEntity.contentLength` on strict entity.

But that both calls are based on entity itself, and that's not what I want.

In my case I'm sending the `Head` request to server(riak) to check if the object has proper size. I don't want to get the whole object using `Get`. That should be just a test.

That's how the response looks like:

`curl -I "http://req-to-riak"
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Riak-Vclock: a85hYGBgzGDKBVI82eqS92f/Ot/EwOT3PoMpkTGPleHKa8WLfFkA
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Server: MochiWeb/1.1 WebMachine/1.10.8 (that head fake, tho)
Last-Modified: Fri, 12 Aug 2016 06:42:28 GMT
ETag: "5IVrr7tsZp1O4FHLnMSc30"
Date: Wed, 24 Aug 2016 12:53:32 GMT
Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Length: 290305`

But akka still return `0`

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug of Akka-Http, see here: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/377